# How do I stop scrolling/dragging past the bounds of my UITableView?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

When I drag past the top or end of my tableview, I get to a blank white screen. How do I prevent my tableview from scolling past the first or last cell?

Comment: Is it the "white" that disturbs you or really the fact that the user is able to drag past the bounds? Both is solvable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can turn off the `bounces` property of your table view in Interface Builder or in code.  But doing so is a very bad idea.

Comment: It's a bad idea because users expect the bouncing. If it's simply the whiteness that you object to, you can change the background color or use a background image.